# topological star compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A topological space $X$ is said to be **star compact** if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}(K,\mathscr{U})$.

$St(K, \mathscr{U})=\bigcup\{U\in \mathscr{U}: U \cap K \neq \emptyset\}$

‎‎‎$ ‎St‎^{n+1}‎‎ (K, \mathscr{U}‎) =‎
 ‎\bigcup ‎ \{ U‎ ‎\in‎  \mathscr{‎U} : U ‎\cap St‎^{n}‎‎‎(K, \mathscr{U}‎)  ‎\neq ‎\emptyset \}‎‎‎$‎.‎
 ‎

‎‎A topological space $X$ is said to be **‎n-‎star compact** if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a ‎finite ‎subset‎ $‎\mathscr{V}‎$ of $\mathscr{U}$  such that $X = \operatorname{St}‎^{‎n‎}‎(‎\bigcup ‎\mathscr{‎V}‎ ‎‎,\mathscr{U})$.

> 1:‎ I‎ ‎think ‎that‎ star ‎compact ‎is the same ‎1-‎ star ‎compact.‎ Is it right?‎
>
> ‎2:‎ Is star ‎compact, ‎$n‎$‎-star ‎compact?‎‎
>
> 3: ‎Is  ‎there an example  that ‎show‎  ‎‎closed ‎subset ‎in‎ star ‎compact ‎space ‎is ‎not‎ star ‎compact?‎‎

Comment: 1 depends on your definition of $1$-star compact. $\operatorname{st}^n(K, \mathcal{U}) \subseteq \operatorname{st}^{n+1}(K, \mathcal{U})$ for all $n$. That answers 2.

Comment: Define $n$-star compact ??

Comment: I could not find a counterexample nor a theorem regarding 3 in a quick online literature survey..

Comment: You did neither define $1$-star compact nor $n$-star compact, but certainly you have $St^1(K, \mathscr{U})= St(K, \mathscr{U})$ and say that $X$ is $n$-star compact if for every open cover $\mathscr{U}$ of $X$ there is a compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \operatorname{St}^n(K,\mathscr{U})$. Moreover, you may define $St^0(K, \mathscr{U})= K$. Then the definition

$‎St‎^{n+1}‎‎ (K, \mathscr{U}‎) =‎ ‎\bigcup ‎ \{ U‎ ‎\in‎  \mathscr{‎U} : U ‎\cap St‎^{n}‎‎‎(K, \mathscr U ‎) ‎\ne ‎\emptyset \}‎‎‎ ‎$‎

is valid for all $n \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

3. Yes, see Remark 2.1 in the paper “[On $\mathcal K$-Starcompact Spaces](https://www.emis.de/journals/BMMSS/pdf/v30n1/v30n1p8.pdf)” by Yan-Kui Song (Bull. Malays. Math. Sci. Soc. (2) **30**:1 (2007), 59–64).